# ERROR: Symbol file could not be found. Defaulted to export symbols for ....\chrome.dll

Tags: google-chrome, windbg

I don't know why I couldn't get symbolized stack trace from Windbg with using chrome.exe on Windows 7

```
srv*c:\Symbols*https://chromium-browser-symsrv.commondatastorage.googleapis.com;

*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome SxS\Application\74.0.3123.0\chrome.dll - 
chrome_7fee0810000!ChromeMain+0x4fbabd:
000007fe`e0d10d3d ff90a0000000    call    qword ptr [rax+0A0h] ds:feeefeee`feeeff8e=????????????????
0:000> k
Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00000000`009fe660 000007fe`e1b3339f chrome_7fee0810000!ChromeMain+0x4fbabd
00000000`009fe700 000007fe`e1f5755b chrome_7fee0810000!ovly_debug_event+0xbef3bf
00000000`009ae770 000007fe`e1f578fc chrome_7fee0810000!ovly_debug_event+0xfdc57b
```

Comment: It is rather complex to learn which symbol matches the binary you attempt to debug, but you should see what noisy mode might tell, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/verifying-symbols If Google does not have a matching symbol file for the version you debug, they you probably shouldn't waste your time on that.

Comment: Perhaps try `ld *; .reload /f` just to be sure

Comment: @Joker frake have you tried this symbol server to see if it resolves? .sympath+ SRV*c:\Symbols*https://chromium-browser-symsrv.commondatastorage.googleapis.com   See https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/debugging-on-windows